# BFS graph traversal in JavaScript working on toy, not in actual problem

Tags: javascript, object, lodash, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to understand this function from *[Hands-On Data Structures and Algorithms with JavaScript](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/hands-data-structures-and-algorithms-javascript)*, as seen [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=GSBKDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA187&lpg=PA187&dq=bfs+lodash&source=bl&ots=FmkF1thzTu&sig=XjRtFH5vZH-mSRfIYowlwDdtIzM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjol-HZwbXdAhUDNd8KHW81Ao8Q6AEwCHoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=bfs%20lodash&f=false) I've converted it to TypeScript [here](https://gist.github.com/jtth/2a8096cb9431142e619d1c48aa51ce3e).

It works on the following toy object:

```
g = {
  a: ['e', 'f', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
  b: ['a', 'd', 'c'],
  c: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  d: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  e: ['a', 'f'],
  f: ['e', 'a', 'g'],
  g: ['f']
};
```

But it does not work on this object, which seems similar enough. It never finds a path:

```
wordlist = {
    a-buff_d-green: ["a-buff_dd-green_s-lilac", "d-green_a-buff_d-green", "f-mauve_a-buff_d-green", "m-orange_a-buff_d-green", "p-chestnut_a-buff_d-green", "s-limegreen_a-buff_d-green", "t-fuchsia_a-buff_d-green", "l-brightblue_a-buff_d-green", "a-buff_d-green_s-lilac", "a-buff_n-lavender_d-green", "o-white_dd-green", "e-iceblue_d-green", "i-darkpink_d-green", "a-buff_t-fuchsia", "a-buff_s-lilac", "a-buff_m-orange", "a-buff_n-lavender", "a-buff_pp-chestnut", "a-buff_l-brightblue"],
   ... (continued for 670 words)
}
```

It's the same thing, as far as I can tell. Both objects have keys whose values are strings that correspond to other keys.

In the `wordlist` object, not all values will eventually lead to all keys, but the `startNode`, and `targetNode` have been vetted beforehand such that by the time `findPath` is called, there's a guaranteed path through `wordlist` given the start and target. (Another function random-walked there; this function is supposed to find the shortest path.)

Is there some strangeness with respect to object keys with underscores in them, or something like that? Am I not using an accessor correctly somewhere? As far as I can tell these problems are the same, but when I use `wordlist` it never finds the target.

Comment: Have you tried to take out the `-` in your keys or actually make your `a-buff_d-green` like this `"a-buff_d-green"`?

Comment: No problem with the underscores, but the minus in the property key is a syntax error. You'll need to wrap the property key in quotes as well. But it doesn't sound like that's your actual problem, is it?

Comment: `visitedNodes` should be a `Set`, and `travelledPath` should be an object or even better a `Map`, but otherwise it looks fine. It's unclear however whether you are working with a directed or undirected graph, and whether your graph always has edges in two directions - your toy objects seems to.

Comment: @Bergi how would using a set and object for those change the behavior of the second object and not the first? I'm confused. Also, it's a directed graph. The keys *are* escaped in the source; that was a pull from Chrome: https://gist.github.com/jtth/1905df62b6fec19c94968c9758b2745d

Comment: @jtth No, it doesn't change behaviour, but it would make the code cleaner and more efficient.

Comment: It's definitely not the keys, the hyphens, or anything like that. Does anyone know of an analysis method to determine the differences between these graphs? I can't import this kind of object into Gephi, or really find a name for it to search around.

Comment: @jtth It's totally the hyphen. Your second example is invalid JavaScript syntax. Try `const o = {a-b: "a-b"}` in your console.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović please see the gist I linked above.`o = { "a-b": "a-b" }` is valid, just like the actual list.

Comment: I fixed it by reversing the goal and start words, for whatever reason.